# Rails ActsAsTaggable - Retrieve most_used tag of posts from user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

With the ActsAsTaggableOn gem I would like to retrieve the most used tags used for posts by a certain user. Currently I have a `user.rb` model and a `post.rb` model which `belongs_to` the user. What I can do is this:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used
```

Which does show me the most used tags used overall. However, I would like to filter that down to only show me the most used tags by the `current_user`. I was thinking of something like:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used.joins(:posts).where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

which does not work since there is no connection established and therefore i cant join the models. How can I access the most used tags in the `posts` by the `current_user`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.joins(:taggable).where(taggable: current_user.posts).distinct.most_used(5)
```

Comment: that does return something but i cant handle the object that is giving me this query. its something like `#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000010727e360>`. I tried to apply `.count` on it to access it in any way but then i get a `Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :taggable` error.

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder I guess check your taggable table and see how it relates to posts and make the necessary changes in the query. Or maybe try something like this `current_user.posts.tag_counts_on(:tags)`. I don't have project with this gem right now so I can't really check

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around with a lot of queries I got the solution now which might be a bit tricky.
Basically what ActsAsTaggableOn does is just assigning tags to the respective model. The tags however are in no way really related to anything else. What is possible is [to assign tag ownership](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-ownership).

What I do now could be considered as bad practice: First the Post is assigned a tag which is stored in the tag_list, then I am going to trigger an after save action inside the `posts.rb` which grabs the last tag of the post object (only one tag can be assigned in my app) and assigns it to the user via

```
@user.tag(@post, with: "Some tag", on: :posts)
```

It would have been way easier to just code the whole thing myself and not rely on a gem, but its okay for now.